# Ionic2: How to read data from Firebase Angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, ionic2, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing simple todo ionic2 application, by clicking a button I want to display data on the view from firebase URL, how can I do that when I'm doing this I'm getting an error at browser console:

```
EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

or what is the right way for reading data.

making the request like this

```
this.http.request("https://taskionic.firebaseio.com/").subscribe((res) => {
             console.log(res.json())
             this.post = res.json();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure both Firebase and Angularfire2 into your SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    firebase: '/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js',
    angularfire2: ' node_modules/angularfire2'
  },
  packages: {      
    angularfire2: {
      main: 'angularfire2.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
});
```

Then you can configure corresponding providers:

```
import {FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase, AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';

@App({
  (...)
  providers: [
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    defaultFirebase('https://[YOUR-APP].firebaseio.com/')
  ]
})
export class MyApp {
  (...)
}
```

and finally inject the `AngularFire` class:

```
export class SomePage {
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.items = af.list('/items');
  }
}
```

Comment: I added providers : [FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase('https://taskionic.firebaseio.com/'),], in app.ts and this this.posts = af.list('/postsfirebase'); in home page and i find no any system configuration or where i can find this system configuration

Comment: In fact, the `list` method returns an observable you need to subscribe on it: directly with the `subscribe` method or through the `async` pipe. See this page: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2.

Comment: Im etting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, when im making http request like i updated my question, I left request first parameter a empty string, what should i give here, firebase address like this? https://xyz.firebaseio.com, im getting same error

Comment: Perhaps you could try `this.http.get` instead of `this.http.request`. What is the request that is executed? You could have a look at Dev Tools in your browser after having launched `ionic serve`...

Comment: Getting body, status,  statustext, headers

Comment: Also what about getting response from firebase, in what format its coming from not json right? And we are converting that into json, m i right?, not fully understood, need discussion,

Comment: What did you exactly received?

Comment: Whole body code status, status code scripts its like whole page code is recieved

Comment: Did you try doing this with AngularFire2? Something like `af.list('/items');` as described in my answer...

Comment: Yes, it made a new list of object in firebase

Comment: And you got the list?

Comment: i got this as response, Response {_body: "<!doctype html>↵<html>↵<head>↵  <meta charset="utf…der.js"></script>↵↵</head>↵<body></body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, type: 2…}

Comment: AngularFire is needed only for real-time sync of changes, or 3-way binding. OP is talking about a simple app. Why would he need AF then ? It simply complicates and confuses the issue IMO.

Answer (score 0):

See below how solve problem using REST API. I have a answer posted here for how to solve the problem using AngularFire- [how to set up firebase with ionic 2 / angular 2 and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530765/how-to-set-up-firebase-with-ionic-2-angular-2-and-typescript/36537871#36537871)

This is the approach I use since Firebase is returning an object and not an array. I loop through the snapshot and create a array that is returned from the call

The Service

```
getDataObs(_id) {
    var ref = this.baseRef.child('bookItems')
    //  ref = ref.child(_id)
    var that = this

    return new Observable(observer => {
        ref.on('value',
            (snapshot) => {
                var arr = []

                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    arr.push({
                        id: childSnapshot.key(),
                        data: childSnapshot.val()
                    });
                });
                observer.next(arr)
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("ERROR:", error)
                observer.error(error)
            });
    });
}
```

The component

```
this.FBService.getDataObs(data.uid)
    .subscribe((data: Array<any>) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.items = data
    })
```

The HTML page

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Home
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home">
    <h3 padding>Active User: {{activeUser}}</h3>
    <button (click)="doLogout()">Logout</button>
    <ion-card *ngFor="#item of items">
        <ion-card-header>
            {{item.data.volumeInfo.title}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            {{item.data.volumeInfo.description}}
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Complete solution here - https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic2-firebase-sample

Comment: Im getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0