# how to subscribe to firebase login events with angularfire2

Tags: firebase, angularfire, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I saw this example for how to subscribe to firebase auth events

```
this.firebase.onAuth((user) => {})
```

How can I do the same thing with angularfire2 and ionic2 and angular2 project?

```
constructor(nav:NavController, private auth: FirebaseAuth) {
   auth.onAuth ... // I don't see any subscription events on the firbaseAuth object
}
```

I saw this syntax in the angularfire2 documentation but not sure what the `|` syntax means and how to do the same logic from the @Component declartion in the controller code:

```
import {FirebaseAuth} from 'angularfire2';
@Component({
  selector: 'auth-status',
  template: `
    <div *ng-if="auth | async">You are logged in</div>
    <div *ng-if="!(auth | async)">Please log in</div>
  `
})
class App {
  constructor (@Inject(FirebaseAuth) public auth: FirebaseAuth) {}
}
```

Comment: I provided the answer in this question you posted already... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530765/how-to-set-up-firebase-with-ionic-2-angular-2-and-typescript

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Iconic, but using angularafire2 (2.0.0-beta.2). Here's how to do this. Assuming the project has been setup so that AngularFire is an injectable service. (I followed the instructions at [Angularfire2 Github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/).)

```
@Component({
   .. blah, blah, blah
})
export class MyComponent{

  constructor(private AngularFire af){
    af.subscribe.auth(auth => {
      //the auth object contains the logged in user info
      // if one exists. 
      console.log(auth)
    });
 }
```

In order to refer to the auth object from the html template (as in your example), just store the auth object returned by the call to subscribe as member variable. Your template code is just checking non-null to determine that there is a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

This has been updated in `"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1"`

The subscribe is now in `authState` from the `import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';`

So in your `ngModule` you need to add

```
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

And add it to your imports and then in your `app.components.ts`

```
 this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    console.log(auth);
 });
```